# Free alternative to PHP Code Generator (PCG)?

Tags: web-development, php

I am looking for a free alternative to PCG ([CodeIgniter Web Application Generator](http://thephpcode.com)) with similar features like CRUD and other actions generation, OAuth Authentication, Page Caching and Admin portal etc.

PCG is a web application for generating CodeIgniter websites using a web based interface where you need to provide the module name, fields and actions required for each module.

**Must Have**

1. Should generate CodeIgniter website.
2. Should have user authentication and user groups
3. Should not be a CMS but generate complete code for website
4. Support dynamic dropdowns, index-able search with pagination
5. Pretty URL format
6. Should be an online tool

**Nice to Have**

1. Admin portal to manage the website.

Comment: Just curious, how much does PCG cost? I can't find any pricing information on the site you link to - hiding the pricing I guess?!

Comment: It is $ 12, but for each website generation. http://www.thephpcode.com/paypal/buy_downloads.html

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. This will also improve your chances to good answers. Example: Assume nobody knows PCG. Rather explain what features you need, what are your requirements, what exactly it should do.

Comment: @Nish Thanks! Much better already. Checking with the link I mentioned, can you be a little more precise concerning the must-haves and nice-to-haves, as well as the environment (should it be a web-app, or a native Windows/Linux/Mac application)? Quoting from our [ground rules](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/455/185): *It's important to keep your questions as narrowly-scoped and specific as possible* ;)

Comment: @lzzy, Thanks updated again. Hope the requirement is clear now. :)